# JMeter, Can't refer to the variable created by "regular Expression Extractor" in a HTTP request body

Tags: jmeter

I want to know if it is possible to refer to the variable created in the regular expression extractor and how.

1. created a http request which send an initial request to a web site. This website will return a token called "csrfToken".
2. I've successfully extract this string with the "regular expression extractor". In the "regular expression extractor" field "Name of created variable" I give the name "csrfToke". I assume the value will be stored into "csrfToken"
3. In the "body data" of the next HTTP post request , I referred to the variable value of ${csrfToken}.
4. run the test and only to see the string "${csrfToken}" which won't turn into the value.

Please help thank you
Regards
Still.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `csrfToke` as the name the value will be saved into `${csrfToke}` variable.

It might be the case your regular expression doesn't match anything in the response, check if this is the case using RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Here is the working demo of the approach:

1. In the https://blazedemo.com/login web page there is a CSRF token which looks like:

   ```
   window.Laravel = {"csrfToken":"AltfIDVfDFdr93igrvMJqoU0ffkelFKEVW6A3CqU"}    </script>
   ```
2. The relevant Regular Expression to fetch this token would be `{"csrfToken":"(.+?)"`

   [image]
3. The appropriate Regular Expression Extractor configuration would be:

   [image]
4. Using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) I can see that the variable is created and has the anticipated value:

   [image]

More information: [JMeter Regular Expression Extractor: How to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor)

Comment: Thank you. it is really because the match didn't return. Best regards